# Release specific version of a package

Tags: ros, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the feeling that the wrong version of my package gets released when running bloom-release: 1.1.0-6 instead of 1.3.1., where the second number is in both the *changelog.rst* and the *package.xml* files. So, is there a way to make bloom-release use version 1.3.1? (I was assuming that it always takes the most recent version.)

---

Edit:

I did what *William* suggested. Can it be that Jenkins is having connection trouble? I got 46 messages in my email saying  this:

```
See <http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-handle-detector_sourcedeb/46/>

[...]

urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error <urlopen error [Errno 111] **Connection refused**> (https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml)>

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' marked build as failure
Description set:
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211463/release-specific-version-of-a-package/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2015-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-16**:
I suspect this is caused by having skipped a step and / or incorrect content of some of the involved files. Could you provide links to the relevant (release) repositories?

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-06-16**:
I guess that these are the relevant repositories:

https://github.com/atenpas/handle_detector/tree/indigo

https://github.com/atenpas/handle_detector-release/tree/debian/indigo/handle_detector

The changelogs, e.g., are different.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-17**:
Ping @William?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on https://github.com/atenpas/handle_detector, it looks like your default branch is `master`, which contains a `package.xml` for version `1.1.0`. Looking at your release settings: https://github.com/atenpas/handle_detector-release/blob/master/tracks.yaml#L33 , you are using the "default" branch. You need to run `bloom-release` with the additional argument `--edit`. That will prompt you to update your configuration before trying to release. Then for the development branch setting you should put `indigo` since that is branch you'd like to release from on your upstream repository.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1